# How to get a hyperlink for the words in a description in an r dataframe?

Tags: r, loops, hyperlink, pattern-matching, gsub

I have a dataframe with words and description. The requirement is to check if any of the words in the word column exists in the description. Basically, we have to run all the words against all the description and if the words exists we have to hyperlink those words in the descriptions.

I have tried gsub as shown in the code. This is an example. The actual data is about 30k rows.

```
data = data.frame("word"=c('python py', 'java'),
  "description"=c('Java is a statically typed and Python py is a dynamically typed', 'java is a programming language'))

ll <- as.list(data$word)

for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  for (j in ll){
    url <- paste0("http://www.google.com/ ",j)
    data$new[i] <- gsub(j,url,data$description[i])
  }
}
```

It’s updating only the last row and I am unsure how to make it a link.

The expected outcome is to make the words python and java in the description clickable links. In the background it has to redirect to a url (Ex: www.google.com/python py (for python py) / www.google.com/java (for java))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is `str_replace` from `stringr` that can replace corresponding elements by passing a vector of values in the replacement.

```
library(stringr)
data = data.frame("word"=c('python py', 'java'), 
 "description"=c('Java is a statically typed and Python py is a dynamically typed',
     'java is a programming language'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

If the intention is to insert the link within the 'description'

```
pat <- str_c("\\b(?i)(", data$word, ")\\b")
str_replace(data$description, pat, "http://www.google.com/\\1") 
#[1] "Java is a statically typed and http://www.google.com/Python py is a dynamically typed"
#[2] "http://www.google.com/java is a programming language"
```

#### update

For replacing all occurences of the words

```
data$new <- data$description
for(i in seq_len(nrow(data))) for(j in seq_along(ll)) {
   url <- paste0("http://www.google.com/",ll[[j]])
   data$new[i] <- sub(ll[[j]], url, data$new[i], ignore.case = TRUE)
   }

data$new
#[1] "http://www.google.com/java is a statically typed and http://www.google.com/python py is a dynamically typed"
#[2] "http://www.google.com/java is a programming language"
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. Is there a way to hyperlink the word Java and python py in the description. But it should redirect to the url's www.google.com/java and www.google.com/python py respectively.

Comment: For that you may need some other packages like [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/adapr/versions/1.0.2/topics/make.hyperlink)